# Examples of nonlinear residually finite hyperbolic groups

Tags: geometric-group-theory

What are some examples of nonlinear residually finite hyperbolic groups?

Comment: Why do you think these are known? I certainly would like to know the answer too.

Comment: Did you check the non-linear hyperbolic groups constructed by Kapovich (in *Representations of polygons of finite groups*) and by Canary-Stover-Tsouvalas (in *New nonlinear hyperbolic groups*)?

Comment: @AGenevois: What do you mean by "check"?

Comment: @MarkSapir Perhaps the questions should be restated as follows: are there any known examples of nonlinear residually finite hyperbolic groups?

Comment: @AGenevois Thanks for these references. I will take a look at them.

Comment: Then the answer is "no". There are no known examples of residually finite non-linear hyperbolic groups.